# matlab, how to get the data point from the plot

Tags: matlab

I have plot a graph in matlab. I try to zoom in the graph and get the exact value of the plot at some specific point. However, the "data cursor" tool in matlab just doesn't give the point I want. But it does give somewhere close to the desired point.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See if it can help you...
[link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100687)

Comment: And this one http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100921-how-do-i-extract-data-points-from-a-plot